# Problem Converting Morse Code to Text using sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed, terminal

I am kinda new to bash scripting so bear with me.

I have a task to convert text to morse code and vice versa from a given .txt file.
I successfully did the first part but when i try to run the second script to translate from morse to text i get this error:

```
  sed: can't read s/.-/A/g: No such file or directory
  S
```

My original code:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed 's/.-/A/g' -e 's/-.../B/g' -e 's/-.-./C/g' -e 's/-../D/g' -e 's/./E/g' -e 's/..-./F/g' -e 's/- 
-./G/g' -e 's/..../H/g' -e 's/../I/g' -e 's/.---/J/g' -e 's/-.-/K/g' -e 's/.-../L/g' -e 's/--/M/g' -e 
's/-./N/g' -e 's/---/O/g' -e 's/.--./P/g' -e 's/--.-/Q/g' -e 's/.-./R/g' -e 's/.../S/g' -e 's/-/T/g' 
-e 's/..-/U/g' -e 's/...-/V/g' -e 's/.--/W/g' -e 's/-..-/X/g' -e 's/-.--/Y/g' -e 's/--../Z/g' -e 
's/...../1/g' -e 's/....-/2/g' -e 's/...--/3/g' -e 's/....-/4/g' -e 's/...../5/g' -e 's/-..../6/g' -e 
's/--.../7/g' -e 's/---../8/g' -e 's/----./9/g' -e 's/-----/0/g' Morse_Text.txt
```

The Morse_Text.txt file:

```
-- --- .-. … . -.- --- -.-. .
```

Comment: Please add `Morse_Text.txt`.

Comment: Consider using a translation file like `-f script-file`, your commandline turns into `sed -f morse.sed Morse_Text.txt`.

Comment: I updated my thread

Comment: The `S` in `Morse_Text.txt` is some special character, not `...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape (prepend a `\`) the `.` characters, as they have a special meaning in regular expressions.

Like this `sed 's/\.-/A/g`

Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Also you are missing the first `-e` after your `sed` command:

```
░ tamasgal@greybox.local:~
░ 16:37:45 > echo '... --- ...'| sed -e 's/\.\.\./S/g' -e 's/---/O/g'
S O S
```

Btw. you will hit more issues due to the fact `sed` works, it will replace parts of other morse codes during the stages.

You should consider including a leading space or new line after each group of morse command.

Here is an example in stages (decoding SOS9):

```
░ tamasgal@greybox.local:~
░ 16:43:47 > echo '... --- ... ----.'| sed -e 's/\.\.\./S/g'
S --- S ----.

░ tamasgal@greybox.local:~
░ 16:43:56 > echo '... --- ... ----.'| sed -e 's/\.\.\./S/g' -e 's/---/O/g'
S O S O-.

░ tamasgal@greybox.local:~
░ 16:44:00 > echo '... --- ... ----.'| sed -e 's/\.\.\./S/g' -e 's/---/O/g' -e 's/----\./9/g'
S O S O-.
```

One solution is to include a space or end of line character (`$`) to each group, like this:

```
░ tamasgal@greybox.local:~
░ 16:44:02 > echo '... --- ... ----. '| sed -e 's/\.\.\.[ $]/S/g' -e 's/---[ $]/O/g' -e 's/----\.[ $]/9/g'
SOS9
```

Btw. this is by far an ugly solution, but I'll not do your homework ;)

Comment: i used them the same way on the first part like this: sed 's/A/.-/g' and it worked. does it matter on this one?

Comment: You are also missing the first `-e` after `sed`.

Comment: You don't have to escape `.` in the second part of the regular expression, only in the first part which is used to match the string, that's why it works the other way around.

Comment: Oh right. Now that i put the -e i only got "SE" as a result. The text file i am trying to convert has the phrase 'MORSE CODE' typed in morse. For some reason i only get "SE" and not the whole thing

Comment: You should provide a more detailed update of you problem in your original question. You are very likely have some typos in your sed line

Comment: Also notice my updated answer, which points out that you'll have issues with partially substituted codes.

Comment: I put \ before every "." but now the result is wrong.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that `sed` will parse substrings, as I pointed out at the end of my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the largest matches are replaced first.
It is convenient to store the commands in `morse.sed` like this:

```
s/-----/0/g
s/\.\.\.\.\./5/g
s/\.\.\.\.\./1/g
s/\.\.\.\.-/4/g
s/\.\.\.\.-/2/g
s/\.\.\.--/3/g
s/-\.\.\.\./6/g
s/--\.\.\./7/g
s/---\.\./8/g
s/----\./9/g
s/\.\.\.\./H/g
s/\.\.\.-/V/g
s/\.\.-\./F/g
s/\.-\.\./L/g
s/\.--\./P/g
s/\.---/J/g
s/-\.\.\./B/g
s/-\.\.-/X/g
s/-\.-\./C/g
s/-\.--/Y/g
s/--\.\./Z/g
s/--\.-/Q/g
s/\.\.\./S/g
s/\.\.-/U/g
s/\.-\./R/g
s/\.--/W/g
s/-\.\./D/g
s/-\.-/K/g
s/--\./G/g
s/---/O/g
s/\.\./I/g
s/\.-/A/g
s/-\./N/g
s/--/M/g
s/\./E/g
s/-/T/g
```

Now you can use

```
sed -Ef morse.sed Morse_Text.txt
```